# cannot fit a long sentence in a table cell

Tags: tables, alignment

I am trying to create a table as the picture below in Latex using Overleaf, however, I cannot fit the entire sentence in the middle row, I tried adding line break but it rather shifts to the left row and joins the text with that row, or the last (3rd) row gets out of the margin...not sure how to solve this?

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Cell lines used.\label{Cell lines used.}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Cell line & Origin & Maintenance Medium \\ \hline
HEK293T WT, HEK-cGAS low,\\ HEK293T GFP, HEK-STING,\\ HEK STING CX43/45 DKO & Human embryonic kidney 293 cells & complete DMEM \\ \hline
LL171 & Mouse L929 fibroblasts\\expressing ISRE Luciferase reporter & complete DMEM &complete DMEM\\ \hline
SV40T MEF & mouse embryonic fibroblast\\ immortalized with the SV40 large T antigen using pSG5-SV40-LT-Ag & complete DMEM \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to use column  specifiers that make cells in paragraph mode, such as `p{some length}`, or `m{…}` or  `b{…}`. `r,c, l` are for one-lined cells. You also can use  `tabularx`, which makes the required computations, given the overall width of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X` column type is defined in `tabularray` package too. Using this package, table code is shorter. Allowing multiline header cells also make better fit of text in cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={ X X[j] Q[c,h, wd=8em] },
             colsep=4pt
             }
Cell line
    &   Origin
        &   Maintenance Medium                  \\
HEK293T WT, HEK-cGAS low, HEK293T GFP, HEK-STING, HEK STING CX43/45 DKO
    &   Human embryonic kidney 293 cells
        &   complete DMEM                       \\
LL171
    &   Mouse L929 fibroblasts expressing ISRE Luciferase reporter
        &   complete DMEM                       \\
SV40T MEF
    &   mouse embryonic fibroblast immortalized with the SV40 large T antigen using pSG5-SV40-LT-Ag
        &   complete DMEM                       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend that you employ a `tabularx` environment to allow automatic line breaking in all cells and set the overall width to `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}    % no (full) justification
\hyphenation{fibro-blast fibro-blasts} % define valid hyphenation points

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5pt} % for a mor open "look"
\caption{Cell lines used.\strut}\label{Cell lines used.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|}
\hline
Cell line 
& Origin 
& Maintenance Medium \\ 
\hline
HEK293T WT, HEK-cGAS low, HEK293T GFP, HEK-STING, HEK STING CX43/45 DKO 
& Human embryonic kidney 293 cells 
& complete DMEM \\ 
\hline
LL171 
& Mouse L929 fibroblasts expressing ISRE Luciferase reporter 
& complete DMEM %& complete DMEM
\\ 
\hline
SV40T MEF 
& mouse embryonic fibroblast immortalized with the SV40 large T antigen using pSG5-SV40-LT-Ag 
& complete DMEM \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's not a very good hyphenation -- "fibrob-lasts".  I'll add it to the hyphenation exception list.  I recommend `\hyphenation{fi-bro-blast fi-bro-blasts}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Great catch!

Comment: You need to specify both singular *and* plural in the `\hyphenation` list.

Answer (score 0):

As Bernard mentioned in his comment, one way is to use fixed-width columns. Another option is to use the `makecell` package to insert a manual line break.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Cell lines used (Using \texttt{makecell} package).\label{Cell lines used.}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Cell line & Origin & Maintenance Medium \\ \hline
\makecell{HEK293T WT, HEK-cGAS\\low, HEK293T GFP, HEK-\\STING, HEK STING \\CX43/45 DKO} & \makecell{Human embryonic kidney\\293 cells} & complete DMEM \\ \hline
LL171 & \makecell{Mouse L929 fibroblasts\\expressing ISRE Luciferase\\ reporter} & complete DMEM \\ \hline
SV40T MEF & \makecell{mouse embryonic fibroblast\\ immortalized with the SV40\\ large T antigen using pSG5-\\SV40-LT-Ag} & complete DMEM \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Cell lines used (Using fixed-width column).\label{Cell lines used.}}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|p{0.3\textwidth}}|}
\hline
Cell line & Origin & Maintenance Medium \\ \hline
HEK293T WT, HEK-cGAS low, HEK293T GFP, HEK-STING, HEK STING CX43/45 DKO & Human embryonic kidney 293 cells & complete DMEM \\ \hline
LL171 & Mouse L929 fibroblasts expressing ISRE Luciferase reporter & complete DMEM\\ \hline
SV40T MEF & mouse embryonic fibroblast immortalized with the SV40 large T antigen using pSG5-SV40-LT-Ag & complete DMEM \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Using `makecell` package:

[image: makecell]

Using fixed-width column:

[image: fixedwidth]

Edit:

As Mico mentioned in his comment, the 1st column of the 2nd table should not be justified which can be achieved by the `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` command. `\arraybackslash` is necessary to restore the usual definition of `\\` in `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Cell lines used (Using fixed-width column).\label{Cell lines used.}}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.3\textwidth}*{2}{|p{0.3\textwidth}}|}
\hline
Cell line & Origin & Maintenance Medium \\ \hline
HEK293T WT, HEK-cGAS low, HEK293T GFP, HEK-STING, HEK STING CX43/45 DKO & Human embryonic kidney 293 cells & complete DMEM \\ \hline
LL171 & Mouse L929 fibroblasts expressing ISRE Luciferase reporter & complete DMEM\\ \hline
SV40T MEF & mouse embryonic fibroblast immortalized with the SV40 large T antigen using pSG5-SV40-LT-Ag & complete DMEM \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output 3]

Comment: for the second table, you should suspend justification in order to avoid outcomes as in the upper left data cell

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the suggestion.